# Eclipse hang every time I supposed to choose file?

Tags: java, eclipse

I got a problem with my Eclipse that it used to open and give the option to choose a file but after I changed the environment, it has stopped working.
 The code is supposed to make me choose a file twice but now it just shows one time and then it hangs.
 I have tried removing and resinstalling the Eclipse and SDK as well but to no avail.

This is my code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        Words word = new Words();
        String student = word.chooseFile(); 
        String teacher = word.chooseFile(); 

        Class Words
        {
            public String chooseFile()
            {
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
                fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);
                File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                return selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
             }
         }
```

> Note: The code works fine in other computers but except mine.

Screen Shot:

[image]

After I choose the first one nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: Obvious question: are you sure, that the second filechooser window isn't hidden by another window?

Comment: I'm totally sure it is not code problem it is something related to the SDK or the environment but I did't figure it out yet!!!!

Comment: Oh, a Mac OS. You might want to search about about Bugs with Swing and Mac OS for Java Versions above 1.6. It works sometimes, but there are problems. As far as I remember it had something to do with the font rendering.

Comment: Just to say I used to work then I did something with the SDK it messed up everything. I tried and deleted everything Eclipse and the SDK and I downloaded them again!! nothing happened

Comment: Try Jave 1.6 instead.

Comment: nope it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I believe it is like bug from Eclipse what I have to do is just delete the code and rewrite the same thing exactly and it Works!! Why?? I have no idea.

Unfortunately, it works sometimes but most of the time it doesn't work. This make me crazy I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

1: it works with  java 1.7

2: but ! it's not safe: you can have an exception in chooseFile 
in getAbsolutePath();
for example, if you cancel the choose window.
=> java.lang.NullPointerException

replace it with:
    if (selectedFile!=null)
        return selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
        else return "";

3: have you checked properties: java build path , compiler ?

4: could you put a step between the two filechoosers ?
like System.out.println();

Comment: I did put step same thing :(